# DICOM supported video formats

Tags: dicom

What video formats are supported by DICOM? As far as I can tell only MPEG format is supported.

Answer (score 4):

MPEG4 / H.264 seems to be also supported. Have a look [here](http://www.dabsoft.ch/dicom/5/8.2.7/).

Information related to video formats in DICOM is included in [Sup. 149](ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/final/sup149_ft.pdf)

Unfortunately, I do not have any real experience working with DICOM video contents. Anyway, I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Just to give an overview of the possible encapsulation of movie style format, one should go to:

- [DICOM PS3.5 current - Data Structures and Encoding](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/PS3.5.html)

Search for `8.2. Native or Encapsulated Format Encoding` (direct link [here](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.html)).

If I quote this list (Feb 2017):

- [8.2.5. MPEG2 Main Profile / Main Level Image Compression](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.5.html)
- [8.2.6. MPEG2 Main Profile / High Level Image Compression](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.6.html)
- [8.2.7. MPEG-4 AVC/H.264 High Profile / Level 4.1 Video Compression](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.7.html)
- [8.2.8. MPEG-4 AVC/H.264 High Profile / Level 4.2 Video Compression](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.8.html)
- [8.2.9. MPEG-4 AVC/H.264 Stereo High Profile / Level 4.2 Video Compression](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.9.html)
- [8.2.10. HEVC/H.265 Main Profile / Level 5.1 Video Compression](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.10.html)
- [8.2.11. HEVC/H.265 Main 10 Profile / Level 5.1 Video Compression](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.11.html)

Of course this does not include the time based (cine loop) multiframe images supported in DICOM (such as multiframe X-Ray Angiographic Image Storage).

Answer (score 1):

These are the supported video formats and corresponding transfer syntaxes:

- MPEG2 Main Profile @ Main Level : "1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.100"
- MPEG2 Main Profile @ High Level : "1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.101"
- MPEG-4 AVC/H.264 High Profile / Level 4.1 : "1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.102"
- MPEG-4 AVC/H.264 BD-compatible High Profile / Level 4.1 :
  "1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.103"

Source: http://dicomiseasy.blogspot.pe/2014/09/video-to-dicom-and-back.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition, DICOM has support for multi-frame clips. While they are not video stream, per-se, they are supported widely to show movie/cine clips acquired by the modality. This is quite common in Ultrasound like (Ultrasound Multi-frame Image Storage, 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3.1) and been around for more than 20 years, as such they are supported by most PACS vendors.

Typically, these will use the baseline JPEG transfer syntax and encode each frame as individual JPEG image. But each encoding is up to the Transfer Syntax in use.

For the list of comprehensive SOP classes, you would need to look for "Multi-frame" in the [DICOM Standard Part 4](http://dicom.nema.org/dicom/2013/output/chtml/part04/sect_B.5.html)

Comment: I would remove your explicit list, since you are missing a lot of other `Cine loop` type instances (eg. multiframe X-Ray Angiographic Image Storage). That may be confusing for new user.